# How to use Netbeans IDE 6.9 for Scala-Lift development? (i.e: setup, initial settings, workflows, etc)

Tags: scala, netbeans, lift, web-frameworks

I am thinking to try developing web using Scala-Lift framework. I have installed Scala 2.8, Netbeans 6.9, and Scala Plugin for Netbeans on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine. Since I am really new to Scala and Lift, I wonder if there are any good Scala-Lift getting-started tutorials specific to my development environment.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might help: http://blogtrader.net/blog/run_debug_lift_web_app

I found the link on this page: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala#1._Users

I found that page with this search: http://www.google.com/search?q=scala+lift+netbeans+tutorial